# What is called in this optimised code

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have a simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void p(){
    printf("jjjj");
}

int main(){
    p();
}
```

If I compile this with g++ on Mac OSX and disassemble with `otool -tv` I can see the `p` and `main` functions, and that `main` calls `p`. Using optimizations (`-O3`) I got this:

```
(__TEXT,__text) section
__Z1pv:
0000000100000f40    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f41    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f44    leaq    0x4b(%rip), %rdi
0000000100000f4b    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f4d    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f4e    jmp 0x100000f76
0000000100000f53    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
_main:
0000000100000f60    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f61    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f64    leaq    0x2b(%rip), %rdi
0000000100000f6b    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f6d    callq   0x100000f76
0000000100000f72    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000100000f74    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f75    retq
```

It seems that `main` still calls something at address `0x100000f76`. How can I check what is at this location? What is `g++` doing here?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't declare `p()` as `static`, so what you are seeing is a compiled version of `p()` which calls `printf()` (via a `jmp`), and then you are also getting an inline version of `p()` inside `main()`, which also just gets converted to a call to `printf()`. If you declare `p()` as `static` then you'll just see the inline call in `main()`.

To answer your question though, it appears that `0x100000f76` will be the entry point for `printf()`.

Rather than disassmbling your code you might find it more instructive to tell the compiler to generate asm, since this will contain more useful info, e.g. `gcc -S -O3` (using clang on OS X) generates:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 11
    .globl  _p
    .align  4, 0x90
_p:                                     ## @p
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    jmp _printf                 ## TAILCALL
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "jjjj"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Here you can see the `jmp` and `callq` to `printf` rather than just some unknown address.

Comment: Is there a way to check what is called at  `0x100000f76`? I assume here is `printf`, but what if I have a more complicated code?

Comment: No. I have copy-pasted everything I got. Maybe because it is not statically linked. But I still am curious how to inspect such calls.